# Erro 405 - "Método Request not supported"

Tags: javascript, json, jsp, spring-mvc, controller

O método que está enviando ao clicar no botão é um `GET` porém no meu JavaScript passo como método `POST` e no `Controller` ele espera receber um método `POST` também.

Meu JS:

```js
function criaCategoria() {
  let tituloCategoria = document.getElementById("tituloCategoria").value
  data = {
    'tituloCategoria': tituloCategoria
  }

  fetch('/FlowerLiu/nota', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  })
}
```

Meu Controller para criar categoria:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/categoria", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String criaCategoria(@RequestBody String rawJson) {
  System.out.println("CRIO");
  JSONObject parsedJson = new JSONObject(rawJson);
  CategoriasDAO dao = new CategoriasDAO();
  Categoria categoria = new Categoria();
  categoria.setTitulo(parsedJson.getString("tituloCategoria"));
  dao.adicionaCategoria(categoria);
  dao.close();
  return "home";
}
```

Meu botão no JSP:

```html
<a href="categoria"><button onclick="criaCategoria()">Criar Categoria</button></a>
```

No momento que clico no botão "Criar Categoria", recebo o erro:

> 405 - "Método Request not supported"

como se o método enviado fosse `GET`, mas eu esperasse um `POST`.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow Vítor. E em momento ocorre o erro?

Comment: @PedroGaspar No momento que clico no botão para criar, recebo o erro 405 como se o method enviado fosse GET mas eu esperasse um POST

Answer (score 0):

No seu controlador a url é "/categoria", mas a requisição no fetch é para "/FlowerLiu/nota", mude a url de modo que elas sejam iguais, a requisição deve está acessando outro recurso existente.